# How to determine if ModR/M is needed through Opcodes?

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code, opcode, instruction-encoding

I am reading the `ia-32` instruction format and found that `ModR/M` is one byte if required, but how to determine if it is required, someone says it is determined by `Opcode`, but how? I want to know the details, and is there some useful and authoritative documents which explain the details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel's vol.2 manual has details on the encoding of operands for each form of each instruction.  E.g. taking just the 8-bit operand size versions of the well-known [`add`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add) instruction, which has 2 reg,rm forms ; a rm,immediate form ; and a no-ModRM 2-byte short form for `add al, imm8`

```
Opcode    Instruction    | Op/En |  64-bit Mode | Compat/Leg Mode |  Description
04 ib     ADD AL, imm8   |  I    |   Valid           Valid         Add imm8 to AL.
80 /0 ib  ADD r/m8, imm8 |  MI   |   Valid           Valid         Add imm8 to r/m8.
00 /r     ADD r/m8, r8   |  MR   |   Valid           Valid         Add r8 to r/m8.
02 /r     ADD r8, r/m8   |  RM   |   Valid           Valid         Add r/m8 to r8.
```

And below that, the Instruction Operand Encoding ¶ table details what those I / MI / MR / RM codes from the Op/En (operand encoding) column above mean:

```
Op/En   | Operand 1        | Operand 2     | Operand 3  Operand 4
RM      | ModRM:reg (r, w) | ModRM:r/m (r) |  NA        NA
MR      | ModRM:r/m (r, w) | ModRM:reg (r) |  NA        NA
MI      | ModRM:r/m (r, w) | imm8/16/32    |  NA        NA
I       | AL/AX/EAX/RAX    | imm8/16/32    |  NA        NA
```

**Notice that the "I" operand form doesn't mention a ModRM, so there isn't one.**  But MI does have one.  (With the `/r` field being filled in with the `/0` from the `80 /0` in the opcode table: [full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017659/how-to-read-the-intel-opcode-notation/53976236#53976236) with `83 /0 add r/m64, imm8` as an example.)

Notice that RM and MR differ only in whether the r/m operand (that can be memory) is the destination or source.

---

**Most x86 ALU instructions** have four reg, r/m opcodes, [one for each direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720529/is-there-a-pattern-to-x86-op-codes-other-than-direction-and-size-bits) (MR vs. RM) for each of 8-bit and non-8-bit. The non-8-bit form has a size determined by `66` operand-size prefix to flip between 16-bit and 32-bit, or REX.W for 64-bit, or none for the default operand-size (which is 32-bit except in 16-bit modes).

Plus the standard immediate form(s):

- r/m8 bit with immediate  (sharing an opcode byte [overloaded via /digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017659/how-to-read-the-intel-opcode-notation/53976236#53976236))
- r/m 16/32/64-bit with 8-bit sign-extended immediate  (sharing an opcode byte overloaded via /digit)
- r/m 16/32/64-bit with 16/32/sign_extended_32 bit immediate (sharing an opcode byte overloaded via /digit)
- AL no modrm with 8-bit immediate (whole opcode byte to itself)
- AX/EAX/RAX no modrm, imm16 / imm32 / sign_extended_imm32 (whole opcode byte to itself)

This is a lot of opcodes for every mnemonic, and is why 8086 didn't have room for more following the same pattern as the usual instructions.  ([Why are there no NAND, NOR and XNOR instructions in X86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65596423/why-are-there-no-nand-nor-and-xnor-instructions-in-x86/65599602#65599602))

See also https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding which covers things more concisely than Intel's manual.  Also note that you can check your understanding by assembling something with an assembler like NASM or GAS and looking at the machine code.  Or just looking at disassembly of an existing program like `objdump -drwC -Mintel /bin/ls  | less`

Some disassemblers even group bytes together in the machine code for each instruction, keeping a 4-byte immediate together as a group separate from opcode and modrm for example.  ([Agner Fog's `objconv`](https://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv) is like this.)

Comment: Still can't understand `/0` in `80 /0 ib`, could you please make a further explaination?

Comment: See my answer on another question about that: [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](//stackoverflow.com/a/53976236).

Comment: @PeterCordes does the `R|M|I` in the Op/En stand for Register/Memory/Immediate? And then why does the last Op/En have `I` and not `RI` ?

Comment: R=reg, M=r/m, I=immediate.  The `I` form doesn't have a ModRM byte; the AL/AX/EAX/RAX operand is implicit, implied by the opcode not encoded anywhere.  So there's no `R` mentioned in that operand encoding.

Comment: I still don't understand after reading this.

Comment: @LancePollard: If you're talking about [Why does \`add cl, 2\` print \`80 c1 02\` in x86 hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65929835) then this isn't trying to answer the entirety of that question, just point 1 and part of point 2.