# What do these x86 Assembly instruction codes mean?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, machine-code

I am looking at [asmdb](https://github.com/asmjit/asmdb) and the [intel docs](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) to try and find out what some of these mean from asmdb:

```
add  |  x:r8/m8, ib/ub  |  80 /0 ib
add  |  X:r64/m64, id   |  REX.W 81 /0 id
add  |  x:~r16/m16,~r16 |  66 01 /r
and  |  x:al, ib/ub     |  24 ib
btc  |  x:r16/m16, ib/ub | 66 0F BA /7 ib
```

What do the `/0` and `/r` and `/7` mean? I assume there might be more "slash x" values, what do they mean, how do I find them in the Intel docs?

Then what does the `ib` and `id` stuff mean, those aren't hex values and hard to search for in the Intel docs. `66` and `80` are hex values as far as I can tell, but the `ib`, `iw`, etc. aren't.

I want to eventually build a machine code generator, so need to be able to understand what these basic components of the machine code opcodes are.

Comment: The Intel Manuals have an entire chapter right at the beginning to explain what all these abbreviations mean.

Comment: The old NASM instruction reference has an explanation too: https://ulukai.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#iref-opc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to see [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html).

"slash x" denotes that part of the instruction is encoded in the opcode (reg) part of the modr/m byte. See Vol 2A Chapter 2 INSTRUCTION FORMAT.

"ib" and "id" mean "immediate byte" and "immediate dword" respectively. You can see all the abbreviations in Vol 2A Appendix A.2 OPCODE MAP / KEY TO ABBREVIATIONS.

Comment: Some explanation would be nice. I see the "One-byte Opcode Map" and such, but I have no idea what that means, is there more explanation buried in here? I don't see one.

Comment: Which part? The abbreviations are listed before the opcode map (in A.2 in the version I linked above). The manuals also go through some examples (in both chapters).

Comment: @LancePollard: Related: [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15017659) and [How to determine if ModR/M is needed through Opcodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55312459)

Comment: [This](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/lecture.html#X77_0010_real_encoding) is particularly good.