# Why does `add rax, 4294967` make `48 05 37 89 41 00` in x86 hex?

Tags: assembly, binary, x86-64, machine-code

This expression:

```
add rax, 4294967
```

Gets compiled down to these bytes:

```
48 05 37 89 41 00
```

I generated this expression to see what this instruction opcode type would look like:

```
REX.W + 05 id
```

I am guessing that the trailing `37 89 41 00` is the direct 32-bit encoding of `4294967`, so that is `id`. Then the `05` is in there. The only thing that remains is the `48`, which is somehow related to `REX.W` in `REX.W + 05 id`.

Here's the background reading I did (over and over again) on REX.W.

### Background Reading

> REX prefixes are a set of 16 opcodes that span one row of the **opcode map** and occupy entries 40H to 4FH.

*Where is this opcode map they speak of?*

REX bits are defined like this:

```
0100
W
  0 = Operand size determined by CS.D
  1 = 64 Bit Operand Size
R
  Extension of the ModR/M reg field
X
  Extension of the SIB index field
B
  Extension of the ModR/M r/m field, SIB base field, or Opcode reg field
```

In `3.1.1.1 Opcode Column in the Instruction Summary Table`, we have:

> - **REX.W** — Indicates the use of a REX prefix that *affects operand size or instruction semantics*. The ordering of the REX prefix and other optional/mandatory instruction prefixes are discussed Chapter 2. Note that REX prefixes that promote legacy instructions to 64-bit behavior are not listed explicitly in the opcode column.

It affects operand size if `REX.W` is set (correct?), but REX.W doesn't affects instruction semantics by extending the ModR/M, SIB, or Opcode reg field, that is for R, X, and B correct?

I didn't see this part: *The ordering of the REX prefix and other optional/mandatory instruction prefixes are discussed Chapter 2*.

Later we have:

> Using a REX prefix in the form of REX.W promotes operation to 64 bits. See
> the summary chart at the beginning of this section for encoding data and limits.

### Question

1. How do you get `48` from `REX.W`?

This is an `I` operand encoding, which shows:

```
AL/AX/EAX/RAX
```

No ModR/M bytes. But implicitly I'm guessing, because we're using `RAX`, that is a 64-bit value so it needs to have a REX prefix.

If I take the magic `0100` for `REX`, and plugin `1` for the `REX.W`, and 0's for the rest, that gives us `01001000`, which is 72, not 48. Hmm...

Looking back at tables 2-1 through 2-3, the value 48 doesn't seem to be associated with `RAX` anywhere.

So I'm at a loss on how they got this 48. How did they get the 48?

Generically, how do you calculate the value of `REX.W` when you see it in the opcode field in the Intel docs?

---

Ah I just noticed it is somehow related to 40H to 4FH. Hmm...

Comment: `0x48` *is* a REX prefix with the W bit set, and the others clear, of course.  https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#Encoding.  In decimal, yes that's 72, but machine code bytes are invariably shown in hex, for obvious reasons, often without cluttering things up by putting a 0x in front of each one, or an `h` suffix, in disassembly.  Stuff like `48` being `0x48` in this context is something you'll have to get used to, to make sense of the tools you're using, like `ndisasm` or `objdump -d`

Comment: `0x48` isn't associated with RAX at all; it's the REX prefix.  The `0x5` opcode is what makes (part of or whole) RAX the implicit destination.  (The "I" format for `add` in its table, so yes this is `add rax, sign_extended_imm32`. 
 [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976236) somewhat covers that.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Funnily enough, I have the POWER reference manual open right now and it does actually show opcodes in decimal.  It's quite a strange sight.

Comment: @fuz: IBM also counts bits backwards, with MSB=0, so the low bits get renumbered in 64-bit mode.  I wouldn't have guessed they'd show opcodes in decimal, but if anyone was going to do it, IBM surprised me the least.

Comment: Also, in my 2nd comment, I meant to link [How to determine if ModR/M is needed through Opcodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55312459) for the description of "I" format vs. "MI" format as keys to the operand-encoding table on the same page (modrm with the destination encoded by M, and an immediate source, in that order.)